# Insert input array into mysql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my form there is two input as follows:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="topico[]"/>
<textarea rows="2" cols="46" maxlength="120" class="form-control input-sm" name="descricao[]"></textarea>
```

which then is assigned into a class attribute as follow:

```
if ($_POST) {
// seta propriedades do objeto
$topico->nome = $_POST['topico'];
$topico->descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
 if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
    if ($topico->update()) {
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">";
        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
        echo "Tópico atualizado com sucesso.";
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">";
        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
        echo "Erro ao atualizar tópico.";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}else {
    if ($topico->create()) {
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">";
        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
        echo "Tópico criado com sucesso.";
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">";
        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
        echo "Erro ao criar tópico.";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

the create method is which I am having trouble because I do not know how to insert these data in the database.

```
public function create() {
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " (nome, descricao) values (?, ?)";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $this->nome = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->nome));
    $this->descricao = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->descricao));
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->nome);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->descricao);
    // execute statement
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For what I can tell I must use foreach function, how would I do that?

Comment: Have you multiple names and descriptions that you are submitting all at once? $_POST['topico'] is an array.  Does it need to be?

Comment: If you dont want an array in name then simply do this  `name="topico"` not `name="topico[]"`. This creates a topico array

Comment: Yes, it needs to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looping through $_POST and calling $topico->create for every row although this is not the best way, its the only way I found.

```
if ($_POST) {

foreach ($_POST['topico'] as $index => $row) {
    $topico->nome = $_POST['topico'][$index];
    $topico->descricao = $_POST['descricao'][$index];
    $topico->id = $_POST['id'][$index];

    if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
        if ($topico->update()) {
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">";
            echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
            echo "Tópico atualizado com sucesso.";
            echo "</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">";
            echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
            echo "Erro ao atualizar tópico.";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    } else {
        if ($topico->create()) {
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">";
            echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
            echo "Tópico criado com sucesso.";
            echo "</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">";
            echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
            echo "Erro ao criar tópico.";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

}